# Async function calls and accumulation handed elegantly or idiomatically

Tags: javascript

I seem to regularly get stuck on handling async i/o issues and always seem to come up with clunky solutions. See this snippet for my current challenge.

Purpose: AWS Lambda function which reads the contents of a DynamoDB table and writes it to a file stored in S3. This Lambda function gets called whenever there is an update to the DynamoDB table.

Problem: see the commented out section of code in the center of the function onScan? That is to handle the case where it takes multiple calls to dynDoc.scan() to deliver the entire contents of the DynamoDB table. The limit is 100 rows per call. However, ideally the S3 file would be written once with the entire contents of the table have been delivered, not on every call of dynDoc.scan() as the code is currently constructed. This is a challenge with the asynchronous I/O to DynamoDB and the onScan callback. In addition, I clear the variable fileContents each time onScan is executed, because, if you invoke this lambda function twice with less than 5 minutes between, it will stay in memory and the global fileContents will accumulate two copies of the table.

One idea I have is to initialize a counter before the initial call to dynDoc.scan() and then increment the counter for each subsequent call to dynDoc.scan(). I would decrement the counter after the commented out section of code and then test for it to be zero before writing out the S3 file and clearing fileContents.

Is there a more elegant solution? Something more idiomatic Javascript?

Note that Lambda currently supports node.js version 8.10.

Thank you for looking at this!

```
'use strict';
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
AWS.config.update({ region: "us-east-1" });

var s3 = new AWS.S3();
var s3Params = {
    Body: "testing",
    Bucket: "my-bucket",
    Key: "my-file.csv"
};
var dyn = new AWS.DynamoDB();
var dynDoc = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient;
var dynParamsDoc = { TableName: "MyTable" };
var itemCount = 0;

var fileContents = "";

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    function onScan(err,data) {
        if (err) {
            console.error("Unable to scan Dynamodb.\nError JSON:",
                          JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
        } else {
            fileContents = "";  // added, because it was not getting cleared
            data.Items.forEach((entry) => {
                fileContents += entry.ClientName + "," + entry.ClientAbbrev + "\n";
            });

            // eventually, we should really loop on partial DynamoDB table transfers:

            // if (typeof data.LastEvaluatedKey != "undefined") {
            //    console.log("Scanning for more...");
            //    dynParamsDoc.ExclusiveStartKey = data.LastEvaluatedKey;
            //    dynDoc.scan(dynParamsDoc, onScan);
            // }

            // Save S3 file
            s3Params.Body = fileContents;
            s3.putObject(s3Params, function(err,data) {
                if (err) console.log(err,err.stack);
                else     console.log(data);
            });
        };
    };

    // Now retrieve the entire table from DynamoDB and write it to a file
    dynDoc.scan(dynParamsDoc, onScan);

    callback(null, "Successfully processed table.");
};
```

Comment: That `callback` makes no sense. `dynDoc.scan` is asynchronous, right?

Comment: @Bergi - you need to see the commented out section, as indicated above. It is commented out because that code would currently be broken.

Comment: Oh, right, how could I miss that.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "*I clear the variable fileContents each time onScan is executed, because, if you invoke this lambda function twice with less than 5 minutes between, it will stay in memory and the global fileContents will accumulate two copies of the table.*". What will stay in memory that we don't want? Are you talking about calls to `exports.handler`, or to `dynDoc.scan` itself?

Comment: AWS Lambda runs the code on some server. If you run it again before 5 minutes have elapsed, the global state is preserved and so the value of fileContents will be accumulating multiple runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In addition, I clear the variable fileContents each time onScan is executed

That I think is the problem. You should not need to clear it - because you should not have used a global (module-scoped, static) variable. You should declare an initialise `var fileContents = "";` inside the `exports.handler` function, not in `onScan`. With that fixed, I would expect your commented-out approach to work:

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
AWS.config.update({ region: "us-east-1" });

var s3 = new AWS.S3;
var dyn = new AWS.DynamoDB;
var dynDoc = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient;

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    var s3Params = {
        Body: "testing",
        Bucket: "my-bucket",
        Key: "my-file.csv"
    };
    var dynParamsDoc = { TableName: "MyTable" };
    var fileContents = "";

    function onScan(err,data) {
        if (err) {
            callback("Unable to scan Dynamodb.\nError JSON:",
                          JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
        } else {
            data.Items.forEach((entry) => {
                fileContents += entry.ClientName + "," + entry.ClientAbbrev + "\n";
            });

            if (typeof data.LastEvaluatedKey != "undefined") {
                console.log("Scanning for more...");
                dynParamsDoc.ExclusiveStartKey = data.LastEvaluatedKey;
                dynDoc.scan(dynParamsDoc, onScan);
            } else {
                // Save S3 file
                s3Params.Body = fileContents;
                s3.putObject(s3Params, function(err,data) {
                    if (err) {
                        callback(err);
                    } else {
                        console.log(data);
                        callback(null, "Successfully processed table.");
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    // Now retrieve the entire table from DynamoDB and write it to a file
    dynDoc.scan(dynParamsDoc, onScan);
};
```

> Is there a more elegant solution? Something more idiomatic Javascript?

Yes, a modern approach would use promises with `async`/`await`:

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
AWS.config.update({ region: "us-east-1" });    
var s3 = new AWS.S3;
var dyn = new AWS.DynamoDB;
var dynDoc = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient;

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    var dynParamsDoc = { TableName: "MyTable" };
    var fileContents = "";
    do {
        var data = await dynDoc.scan(dynParamsDoc).promise();               
        for (var entry of data.Items) {
            fileContents += entry.ClientName + "," + entry.ClientAbbrev + "\n";
        }
        dynParamsDoc.ExclusiveStartKey = data.LastEvaluatedKey;
    } while (typeof data.LastEvaluatedKey != "undefined");

    var s3Params = {
        Body: "testing",
        Bucket: "my-bucket",
        Key: "my-file.csv",
        Body: fileContents,
    };
    var res = await s3.putObject(s3Params).promise();
    console.log(res);
    return "Successfully processed table.";
};
```

Comment: Thanks, @Bergi. You gave me exactly what I was hoping for. Code verified - works as expected. 

I didn't previously understand that you can skip the callbacks on the AWS SDK function calls, but still get the returned data value. I've got to find a book that explains these things in detail, so if you have any recommendations, feel free to share those.

Answer (score 0):

Based only on your code (i.e. I can't assert the general architecture here), you can pass partial content to the recursive call:

```
// one more arg!
function onScan(err, data, memory = []) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(...);
    return callback(err); // see Bergi's comment on your post
  }
  // add current data to our "global" data
  memory.push.apply(memory, data.Items);
  // in case there's more...
  if (typeof data.LastEvaluatedKey !== "undefined") {
    dynParamsDoc.ExclusiveStartKey = data.LastEvaluatedKey;
    // ...pass the "global" data to next scan, and stop here
    return dynDoc.scan(dynParamsDoc, (err, res) => {
      onScan(err, res, memory);
    });
  }
  // if we got here, we have no more data to fetch, so we address S3 now
  s3Params.Body = memory.map((row) => {
    return `${row.ClientName},${row.ClientAbbrev}`;
  }).join("\n") + "\n"; // that last \n to exactly reproduce your behavior
  s3.putObject(s3Params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
    else console.log(data);
    callback(err, "Successfully processed table."); // see Bergi's comment on your post
  });
}

dynDoc.scan(dynParamsDoc, onScan);
```

Comment: The signature of the callback for for the dynDoc.scan() is determined by the AWS SDK. It only supports the two arguments, err and data. So your approach won't work. Thanks for trying.

Comment: Maybe there is a limitation I don't know of (this Lambda system is a stranger to me), but I'm actually using this signature for the `dynDoc` callback: `dyncDoc.scan(dynParamsDoc, (err, res) => {...})`. It's _inside_ said callback that I use another argument for `onScan` (which is not _directly_ the callback anymore, right?).

Comment: What caught my eye is the signature of the onScan function: `function onScan(err, data, memory = [])`. That third argument isn't supplied to the callback. [The documentation] (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#scan-property) shows in the linked section, but quite a ways down the page, that the signature of the callback is: Callback (callback): function(err, data) { ... }.

Comment: In the recursive call, you put a wrapper function around onScan and pass the third argument to onScan. However, that wrapper has that memory argument and it is not something that the scan() function provides.

Now, I could be all wrong because I don't really understand Javascript as well as you experts.